# Selenium ConnectionAbortedError

Tags: python, selenium

New to coding: I'm writing a small script which downloads a PDF after logging in to a university account. Everything runs swimmingly until the final step of clicking the download button when the PDF has been prepared, then an error appears with the connection being aborted.

The error occurs in the second last line of the script, however I can't work out what I'm doing wrong - all I need to do is click the newly appearing download button, and I'm using the same webdriver method which successfully clicked buttons previously.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import pyperclip

#launch url from clipboard
#url = pyperclip.paste()
url = 'https://ebookcentral.proquest.com/lib/unimelb/detail.action?docID=438856' #test URL


#create a Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)

#Login to Unimelb

userinput = driver.find_element_by_id('usernameInput')
pwinput = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordInput')

userinput.send_keys("redacted")
pwinput.send_keys("redacted")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/form/div[2]/button")
loginbutton.click()

#Find PDF download buttons

pdf_1 = driver.find_element_by_id("tool_chapterdownload_438856_1_1")
pdf_1.click()

#wait a moment until PDF is ready
time.sleep(5)

#dies here
downloadbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chapterOpenPDF"]')
downloadbutton.click()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\Book_Downloader.py", line 43, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="chapterOpenPDF"]').click()
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 387, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 957, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 495, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: Please drop the word **shit** as in **#shits itself here** within your code trial. A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Same error!!!!!

Comment: What browser are you using? If Firefox and your geckodriver is 0.21.0, try downgrading geckodriver to 0.20.1.